# How can I explore and modify the created dataset from tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Here's how I used the function:

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_directory,
    labels='inferred',
    image_size=(299, 299),
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset='training',
    seed=123
)
```

I'd like to explore the created dataset much like in this [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/docs/overview.ipynb), particularly the part where it was converted to a `pandas` dataframe. But my minimum goal is to check the labels and the number of files attached to it, just to check if, indeed, it created the dataset as expected (sub-directory being the corresponding label of images inside it).

To be clear, the `main_directory` is set up like this:

```
main_directory
- class_a
  - 000.jpg
  - ...
- class_b
  - 100.jpg
  - ...
```

And I'd like to see the dataset display its info with something like this:

```
label     number of images
class_a   100
class_b   100
```

Additionally, is it possible to remove labels and corresponding images in a dataset? The idea is to drop them if the corresponding number of images is less than a certain number, or a different metric. It can be of course done outside this function through other means, but I'd like to know if it is indeed possible, and if so, how.

EDIT: For additional context, the end goal of all of this is to train a pre-trained model like [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/inception_v3/classification/4) with local images divided into folders named after their classes. If there is a better way that includes not using that function and meets this end goal, it's welcome all the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be much easier to use `glob2` to get all your filenames, process them as you want to, then make a simple loading function that will replace `image_dataset_from_directory`.

Get all your files:

```
files = glob2.glob('class_*\\*.jpg')
```

Then manipulate this list of filenames as desired.

Then, make a function to load the images:

```
def load(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, size=(299, 299))
    label = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.sep)[0]
    label = tf.cast(tf.equal(label, 'class_a'), tf.int32)
    return img, label
```

Then create your dataset for training:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files).map(load).batch(4)
```

Then train:

```
model.fit(train_ds)
```

Comment: Hello! I'd like to ask how I can utilize this created dataset for the model to `predict` and `evaluate`. I hope you can follow up with an answer here, as I can't figure out why it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139622/how-to-split-a-whole-tf-data-dataset-into-images-and-labels